# Datagridview should not clear on datasource = nothing

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am loading my datagridview through databinding. After that I would want to allow the user to add more rows to the datagridview.
This is only possible if I make the datasource of the datagridview to nothing.
When I do that , the datagridview clears when I say rows.add command.

How can I add a new row without clearing the data?

Comment: You have to add row in your table ..

Comment: if i add row to the table,will it display in the datagridview on refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Data-Bound DataGridView control, you cannot just simply add new row by using the cell property of the control.

A DataGridView that is bound using a DataSet can be access only using the DataSet properties. Forcing it to use the cell property can cause an error "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

Adding new row to a DataGridView control programmatically is useful when you want to pull some data from another table to a Bound DataSet with another table.

These links may help you :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c291d580-5a52-422a-b798-fbfb5f799b6a/cannot-add-new-rows-to-a-databound-datagridview-programmatically

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/411452/Add-Rows-To-Databound-DatagridView

Comment: i do have another question. Is there a way  the data remains in the datagridview after the gridview is unbound?